# npm start -- args does not work if I am using that with form another script

Tags: npm, parameters, npm-scripts

I have an npm script:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js",
```

I want to create more custom scripts and to be able to pass param to the start script

```
"start:xyz": "npm start -- --MYPARAM=xyz"
"start:abc": "npm start -- --MYPARAM=abc"
```

But the thing is that if I do so the param not passing through how would you fix that?

Comment: Where should the parameter (e.g. `--MYPARAM=xyz`) be passed to in `start` script ? **1)** Should it passed to the end ? e.g. `webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --MYPARAM=xyz`  **2**) Or should it passed to somewhere in the middle ? e.g. `webpack-dev-server --MYPARAM=xyz --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"`. **3)** Or somewhere else ?

Comment: @RobC I do not think it is matter as far as I can caputre that param in my js file

Comment: Perhaps try something [like this](https://paste.ee/p/rlXZF) in your _package.json_ , whereby your `start` script utilizes a shell function to initially set the environment variable, with the value passed from `start:xyz` and `start:abc` scripts, then runs your existing `webpack-dev-server` command. Then in your `.js` file access the environment variable using `process.env`, e.g. something like [this](https://paste.ee/p/2zx4p).

Comment: @RobC interesting that is woks. Do you think there is no better solution or there is a bug in npm in regards to that? the `npm start` docs actually referencing `-- args` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html I was quite surprise it is does not work.